# How to export some selected records from SQLFORM.grid as doc or pdf format in web2py

Tags: export, web2py

When I click the checkbox before every row, export the selected records as `doc` or `pdf` format. How to realize this?

```
def test():
      form=SQLFORM.grid(db.problem,selectable = lambda ids:download(ids)
      return dict(form=form)
def export(ids):
```

if I set `csv=True` in `SQLFORM.grid` there are some format while no `doc` and `pdf`!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jian,

Unfortunately, working with .doc, .docx (Microsoft Word) and .pdf isn't as simple as you might think it is.

For Word, you'll need `python-docx` that can be installed with `$ pip install python-docx` and you can find the documentation an sample code [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org).

To create a PDF document, you'll only need to import pyfpdf using `from gluon.contrib.fpdf import FPDF`, since web2py already comes with it. But, the same case applies here: You'll need to read some [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Web2Py#Sample_Table_Listing) and write some code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I am sorry for the late thaks.